# ESlint : which config for Promise and Async

Tags: javascript, eslint

Which configuration to use with ESLint to have it accept both code like:

```
return new Promise(..)
```

and

```
async function() {...}
```

This is used in Node.js

Whatever configuration of ES6 2017.... I keep on having errors like :

> 'Promise' is not defined  no-undef

or

> Parsing error: Unexpected token function

Thanks !

Comment: Did you set `ecmaVersion` to 6? https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options or `es6` environment https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments

Comment: This issue looks like it has information that would be useful: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9812

Comment: with this: 

"env": {
        "node": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6
    },
    
I have Parsing error: Unexpected token function

Answer (score 25, accepted):

FWIW, eslint needs ES6 specified in the parser AND the environment sections, e.g.

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 9,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true,
            "modules": true
        }
    },
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    ...
```

See https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9812 for a discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line of comment in the top of the file you are working in

```
/*eslint no-undef: 0*/
```

Or you can change the eslint config file (change the rules)

And you are good to go!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Although I acknowledge that this is a stop-gap solution which suppresses the eslint but for some reason, even after adding 'es6':true in 'env' to my .eslintrc - I was getting getting the same error as OP. Adding this suppression worked for me.